# Error in installing pm2

Tags: linux, npm, raspberry-pi, pm2

I want to install pm2 on my rasspberry pi 3:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

but i get this error:

```
(node:5118) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use 
os.tmpdir() instead.
npm ERR! Error: Method Not Allowed
npm ERR!     at errorResponse (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:260:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:203:12
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:167:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.59-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "pm2"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/JSMTProxy
npm ERR! node -v v8.11.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/JSMTProxy/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I try to add sudo before the command but nothing change.

Comment: You are using a quite old version of npm, try to update it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update `npm`.

Use the following command and try again:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: `sudo npm install -g pm2` > `sudo: npm: command not found`

Comment: Weirdly, removing the `-g` worked (ie `sudo npm install pm2`). Not sure that's what I wanted though.